# Typescript compose function with conditional return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I created a simple typescript compose function
One of the functions I'm composing has a conditional return type based on the input
When I'm adding this function to the compose function, the conditional return type stops working

My question is why, and if there is a way I can make it work?

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAFAQwE4HMBcU1wgCUSAfPoQLABQNEAHmAPYbBQBmArnAMbACWTBDyYBbZgGcIAHgCScMJ2AAaKAEEAjKRQ0oHOBrwp+CpXnmLgJROU3KaRIycvnTVsuo0BuGnUYs2Ll4BISgRcSYpOTdVO3UAJm1dfUNUZzMoCyVrWw17aj12OHinNzxNHIT8xzSyzLdKtXifWmoGZlYObj5BYTFJCBQAOhHMLAk8eABtAF0SAG9kvQwIYE4MBBQAEzRgNDwCYg8xiSGVrc4eQfQeHlUIABsIUUrH55ueIlUdvZI0CQoIBoAF9fNQAPSQqHQmGw6FgkRwCRsNBIKByVQAeW0RSMJ3MlUxlXQ2AmmSgADIoPN9lA4JxRAAjCAYYE1TGU6m0+lMlnAjyLApQFZrDbUkZDIok8b4AGyL74PAaUHUFU0RHIqCMtEYqDYlC41D4zKEyrSABCUAYwAgcC2AMZTCYTwI2mNsk580ZeHNbJoPqt9BtdoBwAwnGgAH49Z7vXSGczWVA8BybNTkvx2CgAIQnIaMkgi9YIKUnP4Aw7JIti+YS0ukhVx5UghFCTVFNHSvDzeh4HmJtnHbCtiJSFCM1RoIgGuDTwUASF7eWS+2XQu9YYjUGSbPzNCAA) is an example

```
type Fn = (arg: any) => any

export function compose<Input, A1>(
  fn1: (input: Input) => A1,
): (input: Input) => A1;

export function compose<Input, A1, A2>(
  fn1: (input: Input) => A1,
  fn2: (input: A1) => A2,
): (input: Input) => A2;

export function compose(...args: Fn[]) {
    return (data: any) => args.reduce((acc, elem) => elem(acc), data) as any
}

/////////////////////////

const a = <I, O>(fn: (args: I) => O) => (args: I & {a: number}): O & {a: number} => {
  return {...fn(args as I), a: 1}
}

const b = <I, O>(fn: (args: I) => O) => <B extends boolean>(args: I & {b: B})
: B extends true ? O & {b: number} : O => {
  if(!args.b) return fn(args) as any
  return {...fn(args), b: 1}
}

const fn = (arg: {x: number}) => arg

compose(b, a)(fn)({
    x:1,
    a:1,
    b:true 
  }).b // <- Property 'b' does not exist
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require higher kinded types to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known limitation in [higher order generic function inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30215](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215), as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30727](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30727).  Although that issue is marked as "needs investigation", the implementer of this functionality [commented](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30727#issuecomment-479657502) that it's not obvious how to improve the situation.

In order to save my sanity I'm going to rename your `I` and `O` type parameters to keep track of which function they came from:

```
const a = <Ia, Oa>(fn: (args: Ia) => Oa) => 
  (args: Ia & {a: number}): Oa & {a: number} => {
  return {...fn(args as Ia), a: 1}
}

const b = <Ib, Ob>(fn: (args: Ib) => Ob) => 
  <B extends boolean>(args: Ib & {b: B})
: B extends true ? Ob & {b: number} : Ob => {
  if(!args.b) return fn(args) as any
  return {...fn(args), b: 1}
}
```

When you call `compose(b, a)`, the compiler needs to infer `A1` as a unification of the `<B extends boolean>(args: Ib & {b: B}) => B extends true ? Ob & {b: number} : Ob` returned by `b` and the `(fn: (args: Ia) => Oa)` accepted by `a`.  It has to instantiate `Ia` and `Oa` to do this, and here is where the problem happens.

There is currently no facility to promote the "inner" type parameter `B` to an outer scope; instead the compiler loses the generic and replaces `B` with its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), `boolean`.  That means `Ia` becomes `Ib & {b: boolean}` and `Oa` becomes `Ob | (Ob & {b: number})` (since it was a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)).

Everything else follows from there.  The returned value is generic in `Ib` and `Ob`, and you get a value of type `<Ib, Ob>(input: (args: Ib) => Ob) => (args: Ib & { b: boolean } & { a: number }) => (Ob | (Ob & { b: number })) & { a: number }`.  Oops.

---

As far as I know there's no way to "make it work".  TypeScript lacks true *higher kinded types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  Without higher kinded types there's no general way to express what you're trying to do.  The current higher order generic function support from microsoft/TypeScript#30215 is a "best-effort" heuristic that only works in particular circumstances.  And unfortunately your example isn't one of those circumstances.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#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-FAsQG6UHGcy2RyoHgUyLkvx2CgAIQnIY2iXrBByk5-AGHZKVqXzGU1ilfPV4dUghFCXVFNHyvDzej8zNCypjXtItgs1HIcIDFBG-BEFrggBUYT7s4ZhuN2nSwHN40t1rJftkqdFej06Y9XogBBawt5S3wY8FGBfZLzAB9UDzN8xTvT8sx-EhgNvD8My-F8oEAXg3ACI9qAN3BKAwW1fpIkGFdiRQIoiBQUUAEhRzyZJ9gosUg1jeMMLFTlyxoIA)

Comment: @jcalz Would be interesting to me understand why HKTs would solve the problem. Would you mind to provide some more details? Thanks!

Comment: @Andrea I didn't mean HKTs would solve the problem, just that it would maybe be possible to *describe* the intended operation, depending on exactly how such types were introduced to TS; probably you'd need true higher *ranked* types, to allow someone to move quantifiers around.  The real issue here is *impredicative polymorphism*, as described in the Haskell-related example [here](//gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/impredicative-polymorphism), and TS doesn't even have the machinery to *describe* the problem. I'm no expert in this, really, so if you need details I'm afraid I don't have them.